# how to parse safari browser history in windows by C++

Tags: c++, browser, safari, browser-history

my intention is to read the history of Safari browser by my program which is written in C++. I am able to read other browser's history through programming but for safari i am kind of a lost.

the file which is reside inside \AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\Safari\history.plist contain binary or maybe encrypted data. In this case i am not sure how to read history entries like other browser e.g. ff , ie and chrome.

Kindly give me some tips what should i do in this case?

Regards
Farhan

Answer (score 0):

It is binary format that can be converted to XML.

There is `plutil` on Mac OS X to convert from binary format to text one and back.
So you can use it to get `XML` and work with it.

But unfortunately I have no good answer what to do on other platforms.
For example, I found a [Perl script](http://scw.us/iPhone/plutil/) which can do conversation but I don't know if it works or not.

You can try it or try to find something similar.

XML format is described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/plist.5.html) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_list).

Comment: i read that before and found the pearl script but in my requirement i am not allowed to use pearl. Plus that script only works under linux i guess. any more idea?